# employment history on college application

Tags: applications

college application on University of Phoenix asks for employment history and asks it this way: 
"Please enter your most recent employers from the last three years, starting with your current employer"

The question isn't directly asking for all employers of my last three years right? Can I just include the last couple employers of the last two years? I would like to avoid adding an employer from three years back.

Comment: You do not have to add them if you do not want to. Listing job history is for your benefit rather than a piece of info they are demanding. Also I would try academia.stackexchange.com since this is more of a college admissions question

Comment: I agree that academia would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about an academic application, not an employment application.

Answer (score 2):

The school you are applying to is a for-profit school that focuses on non-traditional college students. Most of those students have full time jobs including the military and are looking to go part-time; they aren't 18 year olds who just graduated from high school.

This means that your source of money from school is important. They are interested in students who have access to funds from their employer, or through the GI bill, or have enough financial stability to get a student loan.

If you were applying to a 4 year school where most students under 25, then work history isn't important; but with a school like the one you are applying to it might be important.

I would follow the instructions for that section. They are asking for all the employers you have had during the last 3 years. I have no idea if they will call references, but I wouldn't think they will. They are likely using it to evaluate the stability of your funding sources.

Comment: Not an answer but a warning: University of Phoenix is a "for-profit" college which has been fined multiple times and is subject to multiple class-action lawsuits. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Phoenix